# Click on Javascript notification using Selenium IDE not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Below is HTML code,

```
<div role="alert" name="notification_actions" style="font-size:13px;" class="alert-action alert-info notify_actions text">
   <a href="#"></a><a data-dismiss="alert" id="18" class="close remove_notify">×</a>
   <div class="row share-notify">
      <p>testuser has shared his profile with you.</p>
      <div>
         <a data-status="A" data-user_id="7" data-with_user="10" class="badge share-request" href="#">Accept</a>
         <a class="badge share-request" data-status="D" data-user_id="7" data-with_user="10" href="#">Decline</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Code used:

waitForElementPresent

css=div[name="notification_actions"]

click
xpath=.//*[@id='my-notification']/div/div/div/div/a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57bY6.png)

Note: On Clicking the Accept button an Ajax call is working behind.

Update:

I am able to click on Accept button it is found behaving different.I have a verification after I click on this accept button that name of user should be displayed in left side bar under a menu. This flow is found not working only while I automate and no issue if done manually.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: can you post your full html code??

Comment: The HTML Code you have provided is incomplete and also incorrect. Please provide the correct HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

When executing `waitForElementPresent` command using `css` Locator, the syntax is:

```
css=tag[attribute=value]
```

Next use `link` Locator to click on 'Accept' or 'Decline' links.

So in this case; when executing `waitForElementPresent` command use `css=div[name=notification_actions]`.

When executing `click` command on 'Accept' or 'Decline' links, use:

```
link=Accept
```

or

```
link=Decline
```

Comment: link=Accept was found not working. I came to know that an ajax call is made when we click on Accept button, I was able to click on Accept button using Xpath , but it is not working as if we click on the same button manually.

Comment: In that case, try using other alternatives to 'click' command - 'focus', 'mouseOver', 'mouseMoveAt', 'mouseDown', 'mouseDownAt' and/or 'clickAt'. One of these will definitely work. Also try running the test in Slow speed.

Comment: I am getting same result.I am able to click on accept button,page found flicker for a moment after clicking this button .